# Is it possible to isolate y here?

Tags: calculus

I do not think it is possible to isolate y in this equation, but I just want to make sure. Is it possible?

\begin{align}
y\ln(y)-y = x
\end{align}

Comment: [Wolfram alpha is your friend](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+log(y)+-+y+%3D+x+solve+for+y)

Answer (score 2):

Not in terms of elementary function, but if you call $W(x)$ the inverse function of $x e^x$ (it is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)), a solution of $y \log y - y = x $ is given by
$$ y = \frac{x}{W\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)} = \exp\left(1+W\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)\right). $$